# Ubuntu IPv6 route not work on multiple interfaces

Tags: ubuntu, networking, linux-networking, ipv6

I'm using multiple router but only default interface has IPv6 connection. I can make multi interface work on IPv4 by command as this guide: https://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.html

```
ip route add default via gw dev enx582c80139263 table tablename
```

but this command not work on IPv6.

This is my **ifconfig**:

```
enp3s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.7  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 2001:ee0:4714:eea0:74f5:aa75:6d66:e42c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2001:ee0:4714:eea0:547d:f6d1:166c:5d8  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::9334:be68:d859:2981  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether d8:cb:8a:7c:29:b8  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 4255791  bytes 5960314953 (5.9 GB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1101690  bytes 120961050 (120.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enxfcde56ff0106: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.16.116  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.16.255
        inet6 2402:9d80:22a:41b5:a0e8:11d0:e3d6:b78  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::c7a6:1d27:99e5:eea5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2402:9d80:22a:41b5:3b15:f3e8:b095:681  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2402:9d80:22a:41b5:1217:d32b:b08a:91a0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether fc:de:56:ff:01:06  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 8822  bytes 2709066 (2.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 9982  bytes 1915754 (1.9 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 13733  bytes 1816321 (1.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 13733  bytes 1816321 (1.8 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

`

I try this command:

```
echo "301 mytable1" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables 
ip -6 rule add from 2402:9d80:22a:41b5::/64 table mytable1 
ip -6 route add default via 2402:9d80:22a:41b5::1 dev enxfcde56ff0106 table mytable1
```

but when try `curl -6 --verbose --url "http://google.com" --interface "enxfcde56ff0106"`
it returns:

```
Trying 2404:6800:4005:80e::200e:80...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* connect to 2404:6800:4005:80e::200e port 80 failed: Connection timed out
* Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection timed out
* Closing connection 0
curl: (28) Failed to connect to google.com port 80: Connection timed out
```

**ip neigh**

```
fe80::1 dev enp3s0 lladdr 98:f4:28:e1:d4:48 router REACHABLE
2402:9d80:22a:41b5::1 dev enxfcde56ff0106  FAILED
fe80::f4d9:c4ff:fe63:c0c7 dev enxfcde56ff0106 lladdr fc:dd:55:7b:85:1d router STALE
```

**ip -6 route**

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:ee0:4714:eea0::/64 dev enp3s0 proto ra metric 103 pref medium
2402:9d80:22a:41b5::/64 dev enxfcde56ff0106 proto ra metric 101 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enx00a0c6000000 proto kernel metric 100 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enxfcde56ff0106 proto kernel metric 101 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev enp3s0 proto kernel metric 103 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eth2 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via 2402:9d80:22a:41b5::1 dev enxfcde56ff0106 metric 1024 pref medium
default via fe80::1 dev enp3s0 proto ra metric 20103 pref medium
```

I'm not familiar with IPv6, so it could be a stupid question. I'm really sorry.

Comment: Check that your rules took effect using something like: `ip route get to 2404:6800:4005:80e::200e:80 from 2402:9d80:22a:41b5:a0e8:11d0:e3d6:b78`

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's just an example when i try connect to google, the problem is about routing, i thought

Comment: So what happened when you checked it as I advised?

Comment: @MichaelHampton it's still 'Connection timed out'

Comment: That is not an error you could conceivably get from the command I gave you! Please copy and paste it this time.